# How do I convert a table in notepad into CSV format?

Tags: python, csv

I have this table of data in Notepad

[image]

But it's not really a table because there aren't like official columns. It's just looks like a table, but the data is organized using spaces.

I want to convert it into a CSV format. How should I go about doing this?

The panda python packages I am using for data analysis work best with CSV, as far as I understand.

Comment: Are all the fields delimited by tab characters?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a specific programming problem.

Comment: Open in Excel/{Libre/Open}Office -> Import Text Data -> Save as CSV. You don't need a programming language for this simple task.

Comment: might be easier to do with a text editing tool `awk` or similar.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The problem is, the guy I am working for wants me to write a python program that will manipulate the original data file so that, if another researcher wants to replicate the results, all they will need is the original data file and nothing else. Therefore, using Excel to do this, while sensible, I think is cheating because it would be an additional step the researcher would have to perform.

Comment: @SunnyPatel No, it's with spaces

Comment: I would push back on that requirement. You could easily ship a Python program that will do data analysis on a CSV along with a proper CSV. Either way, you're shipping a Python program, and a file. The only difference is what the attached file looks like. OTOH, if you have to do this first step in Python, it's going to be a real mess because you'll have to use the CSV module, and AFAIK it's less forgiving about weird file formats (like arbitrary number of spaces between columns).

Comment: A third option would be to see if you can at least get the original file again with **tabs** instead of spaces, only between columns. This is OK as long as no tabs appear in the file _except_ between columns. If it's all plain spaces, you still _might_ be OK as long as there's only one space between words and every column is separated by at least two spaces. Otherwise, have fun...

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I asked the guy I'm working for an he vetoed the Excel solution. He said whatever code I use has to take the file as it is currently formatted. So what do you suggest I do? The file is essentially set up with an arbitrary number of spaces between columns as you said.

Comment: You say the data is in Notepad.  Notepad is not a file format, it is an editor.  Unless you wish to hack the Notepad program (unlikely) please state what format the file has been saved in.

Comment: As @Two-BitAlchemist last stated, getting the original file with tabs to separate the columns would be ideal, otherwise you **will** have issues when one column is too long and is separated from an adjacent column by 1 space. And even worse if there is missing data within a row.

Comment: @StanShunpike I would ask the supervisor what to do if the current file is in an ambiguous format that can't be parsed correctly. If there is a column with a long name separated by only one space from the next (or long data, same thing), then that is the case. I don't care how many times someone tells me to hammer a nail in with a shoe instead of a hammer, I'm probably going to resist.

Comment: Can't you just save it as a plain text file? (I'm on a Mac, so no Notepad). It would then be really easy to import it into Python using, e.g., a regular expression.

Comment: It is saved as a plaint text file

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hackjob python script to do exactly what you need. Just save the script as a python file and run it with the path of your input file as the only argument.

UPDATED: After reading the comments to my answer, my script now uses regular expressions to account for any number of spaces.

```
import re
from sys import argv
output = ''
with open(argv[1]) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        if i == 0:
            line = line.strip()
            line = re.sub('\s+', ',', line) + '\n'
        else:
            line = re.sub('\s\s+', ',', line)
        output += line
with open(argv[1] + '.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output)
```

Comment: `bash` command?  Since the end-user is using Notepad this is probably running on Windoze.  I doubt your solution is usable since the number of spaces between fields is not constant.

Comment: This would be a great answer if there were a guarantee about the number of spaces between each column. Unfortunately we are not sure this is the case yet.

Comment: Another thing to consider is how you'd make this solution work given the data pictured. The data has a variable amount of spaces between each column to make it line up. If you did this you'd end up with a variable number of commas between as well, which in CSV-land gets you a variable number of columns. This kills the data.

Comment: If that were the case the `Commodity` column would be severely misaligned unless everything under `IndustryDescription` were the same number of characters.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Oh I understand now. Thanks for pointing that out. For some reason I thought it was a screenshot of two different files. Give me a few minutes I will update my answer so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

So this is put into a file (if you call it csvify.py) and executed as:

> `python csvify.py <input_file_name>`

#### csvify.py:

```
from sys import argv
from re import finditer

#Method that returns fields separated by commas
def comma_delimit(line, ranges):
    return ','.join(get_field(line, ranges))

#Method that returns field info in appropriate format
def get_field(line, ranges):
    for span in ranges: #Iterate through column ranges
        field = line[slice(*span)].strip()   #Get field data based on range slice and trim
        #Use str() function if field doesn't contain commas, otherwise use repr()
        yield (repr if ',' in field else str)(field)

#Open the input text file from command line (readonly, closed automatically)
with open(argv[1], 'r') as inp:
    #Convert the first line (assumed header) into range indexes
    #Use finditer to split the line by word border until the next word
    #This assumes no spaces within header names
    columns = map(lambda match: match.span(), finditer(r'\b\w+\s*', inp.readline()))
    inp.seek(0)     #Reset file pointer to beginning to include header line
    #Create new CSV based on input file name
    with open(argv[1] + '.csv', 'w') as txt:
        #Writes to file and join all converted lines with newline
        txt.write('\n'.join(comma_delimit(line, columns) for line in inp.readlines()))
```

Comment: Using `repr` to display is string with commas is great, because it will add quotes around the string, which is necessary in CSVs to avoid them counting as an actual delimiter.